# Can I search resultset from within a toolkit template file?

Tags: perl, resultset, dbix-class, template-toolkit

I use Catalyst and put a resultset into the stash for TT to access:

```
$c->stash->{tournament} = $c->model('DB::Tournament')->find($id);
```

This class has a relationship with "tournament_participant" which I access from inside a TT page like this:

```
[% FOREACH participant IN tournament.tournament_participants -%]
```

problem is, I want to sort the result by a column like this:

```
[% FOREACH participant IN tournament.tournament_participants.search( {}, { sort_by => 'position' } ) -%]
```

but the above does not work (nothing is returned). Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick (assuming the relationship really is `tournament_participants` (which seems a little redundant and ungainly; `tournament.participants` feels more natural and is easy to change in the result class if desired)–

```
[% FOR participant IN tournament.search_related("tournament_participants", {}, { sort_by => 'position' } ) -%]
```

Doc: [DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aRelationship%3a%3aBase#search_related).

Comment: That was the right thing. Thanks! You are also right about naming and I do try to avoid redundancy, but there are several different participant types in this case, and I ilke to qualify them to avoid relying on context. It is a sacrifice for clarity.